# Use a class before its definition in Django model

Tags: python, django

When I try to syncdb I get the error Menu is not a valid class Name.

How can I resolve that relationship case :

```
class MenuItem(model.Models)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    submenus = models.ManyToManyField(Menu, blank=True, null=True)

class Menu(Container):
    links = models.ManyToManyField(MenuItem)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/appendixB/):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been
>   defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model
>   object itself:

E.g.:

```
class MenuItem(model.Models)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    submenus = models.ManyToManyField('Menu', blank=True, null=True)
                                      ^    ^
```

Edit:
As [Francis mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606716/42346) (and as is written in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)):

> It doesn't matter which model has the ManyToManyField, but you should only put it in one of the models -- not both.

Comment: Great, Thank you. I work with the book v2 but I miss this information.

Comment: What do you think about Francis Yaconiello solution?

Comment: This is true but it's wrong to define ManyToMany on both ends of the relationship. Francis has the correct solution.

Comment: If you are going for a tree structure, think about using MPTT (modified preorder tree traversal) https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/ its pretty awesome I use it to have heirarchy on my flatpages

Answer (score 6):

One of these models has a many to many, the other one uses Django's reverse relations (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

So how I would set it up:

```
class Menu(Container):
    links = models.ManyToManyField(MenuItem)

class MenuItem(model.Models)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then when I wanted a MenuItem's Menus:

```
menu_item_instance.menu_set.all()
```

Comment: what do you think about Adam Bernier solution?

Comment: honestly, I didn't know about his trick and I think its great to file away for a time when you will need it. - I still stand by my answer in this situation however.