# Fetch two objects beside eachother in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating Django application, with forum-like thingy. One of the views should display list of Discussions, with last written post beside it.

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    <snip>
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class DiscussionPost(models.Model):
    <snip>
    target = models.ForeignKey(Discussion)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=16000)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

With standard Django queries, I would have to fetch ~50 times per page (one for each discussion).

```
 DiscussionPost.objects
 .filter(target=some_discussion)
 .annotate(last_post=Max('creation_date'))
 .filter(creation_date=F('last_post'))
```

I tried to work this around by adding field `last_post = models.ForeignKey(DiscussionPost, null=True)` to discussion, and changing 'save' method in DiscussionPost like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk == None:
        i_am_new = True
    else:
        i_am_new = False
    super(DiscussionPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if i_am_new:
        self.target.last_post=self
        self.target.save()
```

But this makes circular dependency, and simply won't compile.

Does anyone know a way to solve this problem? It seems easy, but I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your circular dependency:

The problem is: DiscussionPost has not been declared yet when you FK it in Discussion.
put the name of the model that has not been declared yet in quotes.

```
models.ForeignKey('DiscussionPost', null=True)
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606701/884453

Comment: Thanks for your help :) After you wrote it, I found something on Django documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships).